# Upgrade a laptop's harddrive to ssd

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, ssd, uefi

I intended to upgrade my laptop's harddrive to ssd. I bought a 120 GB ssd. 
I used Casper software to copy my current OS (Windows 10) to the ssd. I copied the system drive (C) to the ssd.

When I install the ssd to may laptop and power on the laptop, the system cannot find the disk. I could't boot the windows.

I reinstalled the HDD to my laptop, then power on and the windows opened again. No problem.

It looks like something wrong with the copying files to the ssd.

Is it enough to copy only the C drive to make a disk bootable? There is also EFI and OEM partitions. 
Do I need to move these partitions to the SSD too?

My HDD's capacity is 500 GB which is almost full but SSD's capacity is 120 GB.  It is not possible to copy whole HDD to SSD.

The Casper 7.0 program doesn't see the EFI part.

Comment: Exactly how large is the original drive C: system partition you intend to use on your SSD?  Also, does your laptop have the ability to physically have both the SSD and the HD connected at the same time?

Comment: The hard drive 110 GB large. I can only connect one of them via usb.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking in the right direction. You must copy the EFI partition to the SSD in order to have your disk cloning lead to a successful booting of the OS on the SSD. Casper does seem to fail as you've mentioned and if you really want a cloning to the SSD, why don't you try other software.

You can try [EaseUS Todo Backup](http://www.todo-backup.com/backup-resource/data-transfer/migrate-windows-10-to-ssd.htm), which claims that it can do that migration successfully. This is free to use and if this fails, there's another alternative - Paragon's [Migrate OS to SSD](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/id-1670056/successful-clone-windows-hard-drive-ssd-gpt-uefi.html) which is paid software. Some comments talk about a coupon code which gives a discount on the price of the software which might have expired as the comments are quite old.

An easier way is to do a fresh reinstall of your OS on the SSD, but you must be having your reasons to do a disk cloning. Best of luck and let me know how it went.

Comment: Clonezilla is also a nice cloner, its free and open source, and can perform backups and recovery's. (http://clonezilla.org/)

Comment: @shlck thank you for your answer but i could't do with this way

Comment: @EbubekirÖzcan I did not post this answer, Shreedhar did.

Answer (score 0):

I reduce the size of the data stored in the HDD. Then I cloned whole disk to the SSD.

I tested the disk by loading windows from USB. Everything looks fine.

But, when i mount the ssd to the laptop and start the system, it says "preparing automatic repair" and can't open the windows.

I couldn't find a solution for this issue, thus i made a clean installation to the ssd.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving you advice about what app to try (which we are not supposed to, in this website), I though why not give you the general direction (as we are supposed to do in this website).

To migrate and OS from HDD to SSD, you must do two things:

1. **Migrate relevant partitions:** That includes the boot partition and the system partition. A third-party app that can perform a sector-by-sector transfer is definitely needed. Carefully study their websites and choose an appropriate one that sees all the appropriate partitions and can transfer them.
2. **Reconcile BCD:** The Boot Configuration Data (BCD) on the new SSD still direct the operating system to load from the old HDD. That's because BCD does not deal with drive letters. Instead, it uses hardware identifiers. You can reconcile BCD using the `bcdedit` command-line tool that comes with Windows, but that is tedious. I suggest using Bootice instead. Direct Bootice toward the BCD residing on the new SSD. There are a total of 24 entries that you must modify. Could be more. Use your Superuser abilities!